# Interpolate Array to a New Length | Python

Tags: python, interpolation

Given an array of values say 300x80, where 300 represents the # of samples and 80 represents the features you want to keep.

I know in MATLAB and Python you can do interp1d and such, but I don't think that works for me in this situation. All I could find are 1D examples.

Is there a way to do interpolation to make this array say 500x80 in Python?

Simple question of 300x80 -> 500x80.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html

x, y are your matrix indices (row/column index), and z is the value at that position. It returns a function that you can call on all points of a new 500x80 grid.

Of course it does not make any sense, since they are sample/variable indices and it just means inventing more of them and extrapolate what the values should look like for them. Interpolation only works for an x (y) that represents several measurements of the same variable (unlike a sample#).